# Como sacar la ruta real de un fichero con un Cursor

Tags: java, android, archivo, cursor

Estoy trabajando con el menú `Abrir Con` de Android con el fin de poder abrir ficheros con la extensión `EPUB`.

La idea es que cuando el usuario seleccione un 'EPUB' fuera del programa pueda abrirlo con el mío, cuando pase el sistema me da un 'InputStream' que es el propio archivo.

El problema es que necesito la ruta del archivo original para almacenarlo en una `clase POJO` para posteriormente almacenar los datos de ese mismo `POJO` en la base de datos local
que utilizo (`SQLite - Room`).

Por ahora esto es lo que tengo por ahora:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="content"
          android:mimeType="application/epub+zip" />
</intent-filter>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```java
Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver()
        .query(uri, null, null, null, null, null);

try {
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    
        String displayName = cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
        Log.i(TAG, "Display Name: " + displayName);

        int sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);

        String size = null;
        if (!cursor.isNull(sizeIndex)) {
            size = cursor.getString(sizeIndex);
        } else {
            size = "Unknown";
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Size: " + size);
    }
} finally {
                cursor.close();
}
```

Como podréis ver en el código, puedo sacar el nombre del archivo y su tamaño, pero no encuentro forma alguna de sacar su ruta real.

adjunto la documentacion que estoy utilizando para solucionar mi problema:

- [Cómo acceder a archivos de contenido multimedia desde el almacenamiento compartido.](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#direct-file-paths)
- [Cómo abrir archivos con el framework de acceso al almacenamiento.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider)
- [ContentResolver.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openInputStream%28android.net.Uri%29)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209494/how-to-get-the-full-file-path-from-uri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final no encontre la forma de sacar la ruta `REAL` pero si encontre algo que tambien me puede servir. Lo comparto por si puede ser de ayuda.

Para lograr mi objetivo utilizo una funcion dentro de la clase que ejecuto con el `intent-filter` llamada `getRealPath` que como dice su nombre devuelve la ruta real y/o la ruta que deseas, dependiendo de tus necesidades y como modifiques el siguiente codigo. Es importante recalcar que yo utilizo una libreria llamada [Epublib](http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib) pero no pasa nada ya que no afecta al codigo que se mostrara a continuacion.

**funcion getRealPath**

```java
private String getRealPath(){
        QueryRecord queryRecord =  QueryRecord.get(this);
        File file = null;
        Libro libro = null; // Clase POJO
        String displayName = null;

        // Ruta del directorio DESCARGAS
        String downloadPath = String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS));

        Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver()
                .query(getIntent().getData(), null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
            file = new File(downloadPath, displayName);
            Log.i(TAG,displayName);
            Log.i(TAG,file.getAbsolutePath());
            cursor.close();
        }


        // Si el fichero existe en la base de datos significa que tambien existe en el directorio descargas y retorna un inputStream legible por la libreria
        // en el caso contrario copiara el contenido del inputStrean en el directorio descargas y realizara el proceso de creacion de un nuevo libro
        if (file.exists()){
            libro = queryRecord.getLibroForPath(file.getAbsolutePath());

            // si el libro esta en la base de datos modifica los valores necesarios
            // y devuelve la ruta a utilizar.
            // Si por lo contrario no se encuentra entonces se inicia el proceso de añadir el libro.
            if (libro != null){
                libro.setLeyendo(true);
                queryRecord.updateBook(libro);
                Log.i(TAG, "EXISTE EN LA BASE DE DATOS Y EN EL DIRECTORIO DESCARGAS");
                return libro.getCopyBookUrl();
            }
            else {
                Log.i(TAG, "NO EXISTE EN LA BASE DE DATOS PERO SI EN EL DIRECTORIO DESCARGAS");
                return new GenerateBooks(context).addLibroInDB(file);
            }
        }
        else{
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(getIntent().getData());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            GenerateBooks generateBooks = new GenerateBooks(context);

            try {
                file = generateBooks.inputStreamToFile(inputStream, displayName);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.i(TAG,"NO EXISTE NI EN LA BASE DE DATOS NI EN EL DIRECTORIO DESCARGAS");

            return generateBooks.addLibroInDB(file);
        }
    }
```

**GenerateBooks.java**

Esta clase se ocupa de generar, buscar y almacenar los datos de los libros y el método `addLibroInDB` setea los datos del libro y los manda a la base de datos, por lo que no lo consideró necesario para el ejemplo, lo que si es necesario es el siguiente método:

**metodo inputStreamToFile**

Este método copia el contenido de un `InputStream` y lo pega en el directorio deseado, en mi caso todos los libros son buscados en descargas y si abres un libro con mi aplicación que no esté en descargas lo copia en dicho directorio.
Como resultado, el método devuelve el fichero copiado.

```java
public File inputStreamToFile(InputStream inputStream, String fileName) throws IOException {
        int CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 4;


        String path = String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS));
        File file  = new File(path, fileName);

        OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        byte[] chunk = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
        int bytesLeidos = 0;
        //mientras que podamos leer bytes del stream de entrada
        //en bloques de tamaño CHUNK_SIZE
        while ( (bytesLeidos = inputStream.read(chunk)) > 0) {
            //escribir los bytes leidos en el arreglo
            //desde la posición 0 hasta la posición marcada por
            //el valor de la variable bytesLeidos
            os.write(chunk, 0, bytesLeidos);
        }
        os.close();

        return file;
}
```

**Resumen**

1. Con la clase `Cursor` recopilamos el nombre del fichero y creamos un objeto `File` con ese mismo nombre en la ruta donde queremos tenerlo.
2. Miramos si el archivo real ya existe en el fichero correspondiente.
   Si existe podemos pasar la ruta, de lo contrario continuamos con el paso 3.
3. copiar el fichero con el metodo/funcion `inputStreamToFile` y realizar el paso 2 con el resultado.

En caso de no utilizar una base de datos ciertas lineas del ejemplo no te seran utiles pero no afectan a la hora de efectuar los pasos descritos anteriormente.